# MODULE.TARGET.SHARED_LIBRARIES.libjpeg already defined error

Tags: kernel-module, android-source, android-make

I am trying to build kernel for AOSP 4.4.2 for a device. When I compile the kernel I get

```
build/core/base_rules.mk:134: *** vendor/google/libs: 
MODULE.TARGET.SHARED_LIBRARIES.libjpeg already defined by external/jpeg.  Stop.
```

I understand that the shared variable libjpeg is already defined and I need to remove one of them. Is that correct?

I tried looking in external/jpeg folder and I am not sure which file I have to look into. Could some one please tell me how to deal with this situation.

Comment: Yes, you can't have two modules with the same name and type. One needs to go. AOSP 4.4.2 doesn't include a vendor/google directory. Where does that stuff come from?

Comment: @MagnusBäck AFAIK vendor folder contain device specific configuration files. When I tried removing those files and start building, I get vendor files missing errors. But external/jpeg has just c and header files. I can't find where the shared variable is declared

Comment: Yes, the vendor tree contains device-specific files. But again, AOSP 4.4.2 doesn't contain a vendor/google directory so the question of what code you're actually trying to build is relevant, even more so since your contents of vendor/google isn't compatible with the rest of the source tree. Not sure what you mean by shared variable. Your problem is that two directories attempt to define the same module.

Comment: @MagnusBäck Thanks for getting back. In shared_variable I mean libjpeg, I can see libjpeg folder in vendor/google/libs folder but not in external/jpeg. I am not sure if I am going in right direction to solve the issue. Could you please explain what should I check and remove.

Comment: Modules in the Android build system are defined in Android.mk files. Both vendor/google/libs/Android.mk and external/jpeg/Android.mk attempt to define a module named libjpeg. Without knowing more about what's in your vendor/google directory I can't tell what you should keep.

Comment: @MagnusBäck # GoogleCamera
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_PREBUILT_LIBS := libgcam.so \
                       libgcam_swig_jni.so \
                       libjni_tinyplanet.so \
                       libjpeg.so \
                       liblightcycle.so \
                       libnativehelper_compat_libc++.so \
                       librefocus.so \
                       librs.layered_filter_f32.so \
                       librsjni.so \
                       libRSSupport.so
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

Comment: That doesn't shed any light on my question. I'm outta here. Maybe someone else can help.

Comment: @MagnusBäck Thanks for your help. As I mentioned earlier, when I tried removing any of the folders, I get some other errors stating missing files from those paths

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error states that the Shared object libjpeg is already defined in other module google/libs and you are again trying to create it. So just try to rename the Android.mk file in google/libs folder or in external/jpeg folder. It fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had encountered your error but the solution was not to change any Makefile or source. Simply I had forgotten to run environment setup script(in may AOSP tree: `build/envsetup.sh`) After running that, no error happens.